# What is the relationship between my two apparently identical patents?

Tags: continuation, continuation-in-part

Patents [US9607415](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9607415B2/en) and [US9613446](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9613446B2/en), which I invented and do not understand, appear identical. What is the relationship between these? Are they legally distinct, with one a continuation? Did the lawyers split one application into two patents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one (US9613446) is a continuation of the first one. IF you look at the claims, the second one claims a method and a computer program product while the first one claims a computer, so they have complementary scope of protection.

Maybe the attorneys were not sure about claiming the software parts and the computer in a single patent. (Or any other strategic reason)

Comment: So, I can claim *two* patents for my resume. Did someone say already that software patents are ridiculous? :-)

Comment: Yes you have two issued patents.

Comment: In general, software patents are getting easier to invalidate and harder to inforce.